# For upgrading android application with new keystore file

Tags: android, upgrade, keystore

Is there any way to upgrade android application in the market without older keystore file by which applicaton was uploaded earlier in the market?

Comment: u can publish new app using new keytore but not upgrade old app besouse for which app use only old keystore

Answer (score 0):

No. If you lost your key you cannot issue any updates to existing published applications. You need to release new application signed with new key (and in most cases with different PackageId)